# how to select many different data"s" from two table?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables tableA, tableB
Two of them have col "ip",like this...

tableA-ip
1.1.1.1
1.1.1.2
1.1.1.3
1.1.1.4
1.1.1.5
1.1.1.6
1.1.1.7
1.1.1.8

tableB-ip
1.1.1.3
1.1.1.4
1.1.1.5

And what I want is
1.1.1.1
1.1.1.2
1.1.1.6
1.1.1.7
1.1.1.8

How to select it?

Comment: What have you tried so far please? (Hint: One of NOT IN or NOT EXISTS or LEFT JOIN)

Comment: are you trying to get results from both the tables?  if so you need to clean up the last bit, all those results are from tableA-ip.

Comment: Use NOT IN syntax (see my answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want the set difference (that is, IPs in A that are not also in B), soooooo:

```
SELECT a.ip FROM tableA a WHERE tableA.ip NOT IN (SELECT b.ip FROM tableB)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT ip FROM TableA WHERE TableA.ip NOT IN (SELECT ip FROM TableB)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can combine two result sets with UNION.

```
select ip from tableA
union 
select ip from tableB;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

The default behavior is to remove duplicate rows.
If you want duplicate rows use UNION ALL.

Comment: I think the OP actually wants the set difference, not the set union.

Comment: -1, shouldn't be upvoted. Question is quite clear if you look at the required result *before* jumping in to get the first answer posted

Answer (score -1):

```
select a.id from a minus select b.id from b
```

or

```
select a.id from a where a.id not in (select b.id from b)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT col1, col2, .. , Ip from TableA
UNION 
SELECT col, col2, ...., Ip from TableB
```

To get the differences you can use the **MINUS** Operator instead of **UNION**